# How to Creat a password protected peergroup using jxta?

Tags: p2p, jxta

Im trying to create a password protected peer group using JXTA. For that i have used the example code given in the JXTA 2.5 programmers guide. But that code doesn't seems to be working. It has some issues. Does any one have a working example for creating password protected peergroups using JXTA ? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JXTA 2.5, secured peer groups were not tested thoroughly. The password protected peergroup were already more or less abandoned by the community, since they were not protecting anything well anyway. It don't think this code ever worked.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..after doing some modifications to the code in the programmers guide it worked properly. Im creating a application using jxta. i have another issue. Is there a way to get the list of (members)peers in a particular peergroup ?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The list of online peers is always changing. The answer is no, such feature is not available. However, there are some functionalities in 2.7 telling which peer is directly connected to this peer.